# What became of the crew of the USS Equinox?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

At the end of an episode of *Star Trek: Voyager*, ["Equinox" Part 2](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Equinox,_Part_II_(episode)) (S06E01), the surviving crew of the USS Equinox join Voyager.

[image]

I recognise the guy in the foreground but can't place him.  What I am wondering is:

**Do we ever see any of these characters again?**

Comment: I think the guy in the foreground is Rick Worthy, but I'll have to double-check IMDB

Comment: Yep, [Rick Worthy](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Noah_Lessing). That guy crops up [everywhere](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0941796/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

Comment: aah i recognise him from BSG!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Main Canon

The sole member of the Equinox crew seen again on screen was [Brian Sofin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Brian_Sofin). He makes a brief appearance as a background character in the *Voyager* episode ["Repentance"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Repentance_(episode)), evidently working as a junior security officer.

[image]

The other characters seen being given a dressing down by Janeway simply disappear from view, presumably working below decks or as ordinary crewmen with limited responsibilities and no good reason to be near the ship's main staff.

> **JANEWAY:** *The last time we welcomed you aboard, you took advantage of our trust. You betrayed this crew. I won't make that mistake again.
>   Noah Lessing, Marla Gilmore, James Morrow, Brian Sofin, Angelo
>   Tassoni, you are hereby stripped of rank. **You'll be expected to serve
>   as crewmen on this vessel. Your privileges will be limited, and you'll
>   serve under close supervision for as long as I deem fit.***

---

### EU Canon

Memory Alpha notes that [Marla Gilmore](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Marla_Gilmore) and [Noah Lessing](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Noah_Lessing) are mentioned in the Voyager novel [*Homecoming*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Homecoming_(novel)) as being part of the returning crew.

> She paused, giving herself and her crew a moment to reflect on the
>   sacrifices some of their number had made. The losses still ached. If
>   she were honest with herself, she’d have to admit, it would have
>   been impossible to get every single crewman home while battling such
>   odds. But oh, how she had wanted to. **Her eyes found Icheb and little
>   Naomi, Gilmore and Lessing from the Equinox. She smiled, heartened by
>   the sight of their faces.**

The others, [James Morrow](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/James_Morrow) and [Angelo Tasso](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Angelo_Tassoni) are never heard from again, potentially killed in the interim or simply too unimportant to mention.

Comment: [James Morrow?](http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/22631.James_K_Morrow) Any connection?

Comment: @JoeL. - None that I can see. He doesn't have any special connection to the Star Trek family

Answer (score 3):

According to [Memory Beta Wikia](https://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Marla_Gilmore) for Marla Gilmore.

- In 2376 (for reference, the Equinox episode happened in 2371), as part of the short story [Brief Candle](https://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Brief_Candle) she offered to help with the modification of a multispatial probe. It appears she got similar treatment as the other 4 Equinox crewmembers...

  > *In the following months she grew isolated and resentful. She was forced to do low-level maintenance work, despite being a class one engineer. She accepted it because she knew Janeway didn't trust the Equinox survivors. She didn't even consider herself a part of the crew. She also received a letter from her nephew that Karl died in an accident.*
- In 2377, as part of the short story [Bottomless](https://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Bottomless) she managed to save Janeway, Chakotay, and Paris when they were on an away mission.
- Ultimately she managed to make it home to the Alpha Quadrant along with the crew of the Voyager.

Answer (score -1):

A Nova class vessel has a typical crew of 80, 39 were already dead by the time they made it to Voyager's location with their Journey to the Delta Quadrant. The remaining breakdown.

- 39 dead by 2371-2376.
- 5 more dead by the nucleogenic aliens they were using for fuel
- Several more dead
  By then only Captain Ransom and 11 others remained. Of those 12, 2 were killed escaping from Voyager, 4 killed trying to escape Equinox. Ransom went down with his ship. 
  Only 5 survived. They were stripped of rank and put in "Probation" with limited personal freedoms.